# Kubernetes/kops: error attaching EBS volume to instance. You are not authorized to perform this operation. Error 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, kubectl, kops

I tested kubernetes deployment with EBS volume mounting on AWS cluster provisioned by kops. This is deployment yml file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: helloworld-deployment-volume
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: helloworld
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: k8s-demo
        image: wardviaene/k8s-demo
        ports:
        - name: nodejs-port
          containerPort: 3000
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /myvol
          name: myvolume
      volumes:
      - name: myvolume
        awsElasticBlockStore:
          volumeID: <volume_id>
```

After `kubectl create -f <path_to_this_yml>`, I got the following message in pod description:

```
Attach failed for volume "myvolume" : Error attaching EBS volume "XXX" to instance "YYY": "UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. status code: 403
```

Looks like this is just a permission issue. Ok, I checked policy for node role `IAM` -> `Roles` -> `nodes.<my_domain>` and found that there where no actions which allow to manipulate volumes, there was only `ec2:DescribeInstances` action by default. So I added `AttachVolume` and `DetachVolume` actions:

```
    {
        "Sid": "kopsK8sEC2NodePerms",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "ec2:AttachVolume",
            "ec2:DetachVolume"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    },
```

And this didn't help. I'm still getting that error:

```
Attach failed for volume "myvolume" : Error attaching EBS volume "XXX" to instance "YYY": "UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I found a solution. It's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47278433/need-help-on-volume-mount-issue-with-kubernetes).

In kops 1.8.0-beta.1, master node requires you to tag the AWS volume with:

`KubernetesCluster`: `<clustername-here>`

So it's necessary to create EBS volume with that tag by using `awscli`:

```
aws ec2 create-volume --size 10 --region eu-central-1 --availability-zone eu-central-1a --volume-type gp2 --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=volume,Tags=[{Key=KubernetesCluster,Value=<clustername-here>}]'
```

or you can tag it by manually in `EC2` -> `Volumes` -> `Your volume` -> `Tags`

That's it.

***EDIT:***

The right cluster name can be found within EC2 instances tags which are part of cluster. Key is the same: `KubernetesCluster`.

Comment: Thx for solution. But I'm getting new error. Unable to mount volumes for pod "XXX": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "XXX"/"XXX". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[my-volume]. Did you experience the same error?

Comment: Interesting. No, I didnt encounter such issue, I even have no idea what it's related to.

Comment: I found solution. Issue was due to xfs FS. This bug is related to the kubernetes issue.